# How to target and style specific elements using CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm a bit of a noob when it comes to HTML and CSS but here goes...

Not sure what it's called but in the following example how do i write CSS so **ONLY** the paragraph tag withing each of the elements is styled?  For example how would you write CSS to make only

paragraph's within wrapper>content to float left

and

paragraph's within wrapper>sideContent to float right?  All other paragraphs should be unaffected.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content">
        <p>lorem ipsum...</p>
    </div>
    <div id="sideContent">
        <p>lorem ipsum...</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>lorem ipsum...</p>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Not sure if this is valid but something along the lines of:

```
#wrapper #content p
{
  float: left;
}

#wrapper #sideContent p
{
  float: right;
}
```

Btw - What is this technique called?

Comment: Here is a [website](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/) to check for CSS validity. You may find it helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS is valid for what you say you want to do. However, doing it this way will make the `p` within `#content` float inside the `#content` div (same for the `p` within `#sideContent`), they are not going to float on each side of the other paragraph. `#content` and `#sideContent` will still behave like normal divs and the second one will appear beneath the other.

What you most likely want is to float the divs themselves:

```
#content
{
  float: left;
}

#sideContent
{
  float: right;
}
```

Notice the lack of `p` and the `#wrapper` is not necessary since both divs should be unique anyway (since you gave them an id).